# Invoke-Command -asJob with variables

Tags: variables, powershell, remoting

I am trying to use Invoke-Command -asJob to run a PS1 with arguments on a list of remote machines, and I am having a bugger of a time getting variables to work. As I understand it the code block that runs remotely cannot normally use local variables, but I have found a number of solutions that seem like they are supposed to solve the problem. I started with this, but it has the local variables.

```
foreach ($machine in $Machines) {
    Invoke-Command -computerName:$machine –scriptblock {
        & powershell.exe  -executionpolicy bypass -file $filePath -jobsfile $jobsFile
    } -credential:$credential  -authentication:CredSSP –asJob -jobName:$machine > $null
}
```

I also tried using -argumentList where $arguments includes the two arguments that contain variables. (I also tried a variant of that where -Path is a literal and and just the -jobFile argument for the PS1 is included in arguments.)

```
foreach ($machine in $Machines) {
    Invoke-Command -computerName:$machine -argumentList:$arguments –scriptblock {
        & powershell.exe  -executionpolicy bypass
    } -credential:$credential  -authentication:CredSSP –asJob -jobName:$machine > $null
}
```

Lastly I tried the using: approach.

```
foreach ($machine in $Machines) {
    Invoke-Command -computerName:$machine –scriptblock {
        & powershell.exe  -executionpolicy bypass -file $using:filePath -jobsfile $using:jobsFile
    } -credential:$credential  -authentication:CredSSP –asJob -jobName:$machine > $null
}
```

So far nothing works, so any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the working solution was

```
foreach ($machine in $Machines) {
    Invoke-Command -computerName:$machine -argumentList: $filePath, $jobsFile –scriptblock {
        param (
            [String]$file,
            [String]$jobsFile
        )
        & powershell.exe  -executionpolicy bypass -file $file -jobsFile $jobsFile
    } -credential:$credential  -authentication:CredSSP –asJob -jobName:$machine > $null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for remote powershell
if you are in workgroup in clients run powershell as administrator

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

for configure trust host for connect you should trusted from clients

```
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts *
```

reset winrm service

```
Restart-Service WinRM
```

now you can use

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER -ScriptBlock { COMMAND } -credential USERNAME
```

you should configure firewall for winrm 
you can use this method for run your script

```
$script = {Get-EventLog -LogName System -Newest 10 | where { $_.Index -ge 5071811 } | sort Index}
```

then

```
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes( $script))
```

get encoded command and use like

```
powershell -encodedcommand **encoded**
```

that is possible when you enter with psremoting

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName COMPUTER -Credential USER
```

your code:

```
foreach ($machine in $Machines) {
    Invoke-Command -computerName:$machine –scriptblock {
        & powershell.exe  -executionpolicy bypass -file $using:filePath -jobsfile $using:jobsFile
    } -credential:$credential  -authentication:CredSSP –asJob -jobName:$machine > $null
}
```

my code:

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName Server1.Domain44.Corpnet.Fabrikam.com -Credential Domain01\Admin01
Invoke-Command -FilePath c:\scripts\test.ps1 -session $s -Asjob
```

Comment: Hidd3n,I'm sorry my post was a little unclear. I do have these settings addressed, and when I use literal strings instead of variables the code works like a charm. It is just the issue of local variables in the code block that I am having issues.

Comment: Ah, an epiphany strikes. The contents of -ArgumentList isn't sent to the PS1 referenced in Invoke-Command, its sent to the code block that CONTAINS Invoke-Command. And that code block needs two Params to receive those arguments and use them. I've updated my code and I have some new errors to deal with, but it looks like progress at least.